# How can I convert the number 1 into date value 20150101 (yyyyMMdd)?

Tags: string, matlab, date

How can I convert `A`:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ... 731]
```

into a date value of type yyyyMMdd:

```
B = [ 20150101 20150102 20150103 20150104 20150105 ... 20161231]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [datenum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to find the numeric value associated with `20150101`:

```
baseDate = datenum('20150101','yyyymmdd');

baseDate =  735965
```

If you subtract 1 from this, you can use it to generate all of the dates from [datestr](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html):

```
baseDate = baseDate - 1;
A = [1:5, 731];
datestr(A + baseDate,'yyyymmdd')

ans =

20150101
20150102
20150103
20150104
20150105
20161231
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of [date numbers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) from the values in `A`, convert these to [date strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html), then [convert these strings to numeric values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
B = str2num(datestr(datenum(2015, 1, A), 'yyyymmdd')).';
```

...and for those who are averse to messing with string conversions, here's some [`datevec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) and [matrix multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) for you:

```
B = (datevec(datenum(2015, 1, A))*[10000; 100; 1; 0; 0; 0]).';
```

Comment: lol... I always find it amusing that `2015/01/397` is `2016/02/01`. Convenient, but weird. ;)